# jQuery Chosen plugin not sending multiple data to Symfony2 app

Tags: jquery, symfony

I have a Symfony2 form that has a multiple select box. This is the code...

```
$builder
    ->add('resources', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle:Entity',
            'property' => 'name',
            'label' => 'product.titles.select_box',
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'chosen',
                'data-placeholder' => '-- Choose something --',
                'multiple' => true

            )
        ))
```

I initialize Chosen just like it should...

```
    $('.chosen').chosen({
        no_results_text: "Nothing found"
    });
```

But, when the data is submitted, i only receive the last selected entity, not everything. What could be the problem here?

If this is Chosen default behaviour, does anyone have any suggestions on some jquery plugin that send all the selected data?

Comment: Can you give a try in removing `'multiple' => true`? Maybe it overrides Chosen behaviour.

Comment: Then it only select one. Multiple is the wanted behaviour. I want all selected options to be sent to the server.

Comment: Can you `var_dump()` the data sent to the server and gives us the output?

Comment: It's the value attribute of the last selected value if you choose $builder->add('field', 'choice') and the last selected entity if you choose $builder->add('field', 'entity'). In every case, it's the last selected value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you show us how you try to access your data after your form is submitted? I tried to reproduce your problem, but it seems it works just as fine. Sample form, rendering 2 multiple choice fields - one comming from entity, and one with provided array of values:

```
$builder = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('color', 'entity',
            array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle:Color',
                'property' => 'name',
                'multiple' => true
            )
        )
        ->add('choiceColor', 'choice',
            array(
                'choices' => array(
                    'red' => 'red',
                    'blue' => 'blue',
                    'green' => 'green',
                    'yellow' => 'yellow'
                ),
                'multiple' => true
            )
        )
        ->add('submit', 'submit')
        ->getForm()
    ;
```

Then, simply dumping the form data after submit

```
$builder->handleRequest($request);

$data = $builder->getData();
var_dump($data);
```

I get the following result:

```
array (size=2)
  'color' => 
    object(Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection)[447]
      private 'elements' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => 
            object(AppBundle\Entity\Color)[466]
              ...
          1 => 
            object(AppBundle\Entity\Color)[467]
              ...
  'choiceColor' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'green' (length=5)
      1 => string 'yellow' (length=6)
```

As you can see, the field mapped to an entity returns `ArrayCollection` of objects, and the one mapped with plain array returns `array (size=2)`

So may be the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: I'll test it and let you know. I tried var_dump in the entity, that is Entity::setResources(array $resources) and it gives me one value. Throws an error beacuse it's not an array, of course. I'll try it out and let you know.

Comment: Alright, just look closely how exactly you access your data. The code snipped I showd you, I dump the data I got *from* the form with `->getData()` method.

Comment: No. Tested it and I still get only one entity altough I send multiple. I think I'm gonna try select2. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. I was stupid. This is the code i I was using.

```
$builder
   ->add('resources', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'AppBundle:Entity',
        'property' => 'name',
        'label' => 'product.titles.select_box',
        'attr' => array(
            'class' => 'chosen',
            'data-placeholder' => '-- Choose something --',
            'multiple' => true
        )
    ))
```

This is the code that works. The only change is that `multiple => true` is defined in the root `options` array, not `attr` array. Stupid mistake.

```
$builder
   ->add('resources', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'AppBundle:Entity',
        'property' => 'name',
        'label' => 'product.titles.select_box',
        'attr' => array(
            'class' => 'chosen',
            'data-placeholder' => '-- Choose something --'
        )
        'multiple' => true
    ))
```